# How to query GHTorrent's (SQL-like language) for country/city/users number/repositories number?

Tags: github, google-bigquery

I've read a lot of documentation on GitHub data retrieval and viewed Github user commits/pushes data via BiGQuery but failed to find city, country fields and failed to find any description on such queries. Though there is information that such queries are theoretically possible - https://gist.github.com/kelewis/4bc942f9433c41b1ddb6/. But this requires Azure lake (??) . Does anyone know how to query Github data via /My_SQL/Postgres/BigQuery/, or any python (Jupiter) SQL like functions - for example pandas DataFrames with "country" and "city" fields?

Smth like this example
.......................

SELECT
city, country,
SUM(number) AS total
FROM
`ghtorrent-bq.ght.commits`
GROUP BY
country, region
ORDER BY
total DESC
LIMIT
10000
.......
Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

below should be good starting point for you (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT city, country_code, count(*) AS total 
FROM `ghtorrent-bq.ght.commits` AS c
JOIN `ghtorrent-bq.ght.users` AS u
ON c.Committer_Id = u.id
WHERE NOT u.fake 
GROUP BY country_code, city 
ORDER BY total DESC 
LIMIT 10000
```