# How to query GHTorrent's (SQL-like language) for most common languages per country

Tags: mysql, sql, github, google-bigquery

Based on this question [How to query GHTorrent's (SQL-like language) for country/city/users number/repositories number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65460086/how-to-query-ghtorrents-sql-like-language-for-country-city-users-number-repos) and first query here https://ghtorrent.org/gcloud.html, I am trying to get an sql query to get the most common coding language per country and ideally per month/year from the GHtorrent bigquery database. I have tried to edit this answer code https://stackoverflow.com/a/65460166/10624798/, but fail to get the correct join. My ideal outcome would looks something like this

| country | Year | Month | Language | Number of commits | total_bytes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | 2016 | Jan | Python | 10000 | 46789390 |
| CH | 2016 | Jan | Java | 20000 | 5679304 |

Basically, I am not very good at creating SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the two examples of the query that you passed, then I found the common value that was the `project_id` and I modified the second example to bring the `project_id` and the `created_date` of the commits. Then I decided as you mention to format the `created_date` to bring the year and the month and  to add it as a filter.

Then I join the two examples in a `CTE` and I only `SELECT` the names of the columns that are needed.

Finally I used a [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions#row_number) only to bring the maximum value of the processed bytes of every language by country/year/month.

```
WITH ltb as(
 select pl3.lang, sum(pl3.size) as total_bytes, pl3.project_id
from (
 select pl2.bytes as size, pl2.language as lang, pl2.project_id
 from (
   select pl.language as lang, max(pl.created_at) as latest, pl.project_id as project_id
   from `ghtorrent-bq.ght.project_languages` pl
     join `ghtorrent-bq.ght.projects` p on p.id = pl.project_id
   where p.deleted is false
     and p.forked_from is null
   group by lang, project_id
 ) pl1 join `ghtorrent-bq.ght.project_languages` pl2 on pl1.project_id = pl2.project_id
                                       and pl1.latest = pl2.created_at
                                       and pl1.lang = pl2.language
) pl3
group by pl3.lang, pl3.project_id
order by total_bytes desc
), fprt as(
SELECT country_code, count(*) AS NoOfCommits, c.project_id,
FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%m", c.created_at)
 AS formattedmonth,FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%b", c.created_at)
 AS formattedmonthname, FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y", c.created_at)
 AS formattedyear,
FROM `ghtorrent-bq.ght.commits` AS c
JOIN `ghtorrent-bq.ght.users` AS u
ON c.Committer_Id = u.id
WHERE NOT u.fake and country_code is not null
GROUP BY country_code, c.project_id, formattedmonth, formattedyear, formattedmonthname
ORDER BY NoOfCommits DESC
), almst as(
SELECT country_code,formattedmonth, formattedmonthname, formattedyear, lang, NoOfCommits, total_bytes FROM fprt JOIN ltb
on ltb.project_id=fprt.project_id
where country_code is not null
)
SELECT country_code, formattedyear as year, formattedmonthname as month, lang, NoOfCommits, total_bytes
FROM
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country_code, formattedyear, formattedmonth ORDER BY total_bytes DESC) rn
   FROM almst
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY formattedyear asc, formattedmonth asc
```

Output:

[image]